# How likely is it that I can use simple linear regression to predict?

Tags: regression, data-visualization, residuals, linear

This is a simple linear fit between height as independent variable and density as dependent variable. I want to know if I can trust that I can use simple linear regression. Goodness of fit shows that the model fits very good.
The residual plot shows high residuals on the highest and lowest y values. How can I find out if its likely that this high residuals are random or not? 
[image]

Linear model Poly1:
     f(x) = p1*x + p2

Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):

p1 =  -0.0001176  (-0.0001208, -0.0001145)

p2 =       1.255  (1.252, 1.258)

Goodness of fit:

SSE: 4.342e-05

R-square: 0.998

Adjusted R-square: 0.9978

RMSE: 0.001827

[image]

Comment: Your model assumes the data are random, and therefore so are the residuals, so could you clarify what you mean by "random or not"?

Comment: Consider that the fit is being affected by the largest observation (leftmost in the plot) and ponder two alternatives: (i) that the assumption of linearity is at fault and the true mean increases more rapidly than linearly near the left end; or (ii) that the linearity assumption is fine but one of the other assumptions is flawed (it's possible for more than one of the other assumptions to produce such an outcome). The choice about *which* it might be cannot be made from this plot alone. Theoretical considerations / knowledge of the properties of the variables will be important.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the plot of residuals versus fitted values, you will see that most of the residuals are negative (hence located below the horizontal line going through zero). This suggests that your model tends to overestimate the mean value of density at a given height and it can't be trusted for estimation or prediction. Either a linear relationship between the two variables is not appropriate or it may be appropriate after transforming one or both of the variables (e.g., log-transformation).

Answer (score 0):

Consider to **rescale** your independent variable as it's too big for the y-axis. You're forcing your slope to zero, so your model is marginally better than the only-intercept model. Rescale it to something like **Hoyde per 1000.**